# What constraints should I use to have an image view aspect fill the bottom half of its superview?

Tags: ios

I want to create a storyboard as my launch screen.  I'd like the bottom half of the screen to have an image fill the space while maintaining its aspect ratio (it can either  overflow downwards, or left & right equally in order to maintain the aspect ratio, I don't mind which).  The top half of the screen will empty.

Having fought for this for hours and haven't got anywhere - I can't even make the image fill the bottom half of the screen, nevermind maintain aspect ratio.

What constraints should I use to have an image view aspect fill the bottom half of its superview?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as constraints go, you can set the image view's height equal to its superview's height then add a multiple of 0.5 to that constraint so that the image view is half the height of its superview; then align the right, left, and bottom margins to the superview's right, left and bottom margins.

To maintain the aspect ratio and fill the image view with the image, you can set the view's content mode to Aspect Fill.

But since Aspect Fill will still center the image both vertically and horizontally, if you want the image to "overflow downwards, or left & right equally" and not upwards, you can crop the image programmatically to only include the top part of the image that would be visible within the image view. For example, to only show the top half of the image:

```
override func viewDidLayoutSubviews() {
    imageView.layer.contentsRect = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 1.0, height: 0.5)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I dont know if its possible using autoLayout only but heres how i would do it:

You can try adding leading, bottom and trailing constraints to superview and set the imageView height to a random value (you will change this as soon as image gets downloaded if you are using a web service). Now you can make an outlet in your file of this height constraint. As soon as you get the image you can resize it to fit the screen while keeping width to screen bounds and maintaining its aspect ratio. Update the height constraint accordingly to the size of the image you obtain.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend auto layout.

First of all drag n drop a uiview (after you will make it hidden) 
make it 1 px height doesn't matter the width (if you want make it 0px from left and right).
Now center this view vertical.

Drag your image view and put a vertical spacing with the view (and of course with bottom left and right)

Hope this helps.